# Debian 3.1 / Apache2 does not restart after update

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian

I just ran updates with apt-get on my debian 3.1 server updating apache2 and php.
After the updates I can't get my apache server up again.

`/etc/init.d/apache2 start` gives no error but checking the processes the server is not running afterwards

When I try to start it by

```
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

I get the error

```
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

I already checked with netstat but no process is listening on port 80.

What else can I do or check?

Comment: Check apache log files and if they are empty or not updated you need to check their permissions. The error `Unable to open logs` seems to be permissions problem in the log files/folder.

Comment: confirm that you are doing this as super user and do report what you see in apache logs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, the permissions where OK.But I found the problem in the php_err log. I had e_accelerator compiled for the old php version and so the server did not start.

Unfortunately the error message was misleading.

Thanks for your time and effort!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are root ? Usually the logs error comes if your are a normal user. You need to be root to have access to port 80.